# Conversion of a pandas series to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to convert a pandas series into a normal list. What is the easiest way to do this?

I've tried the following and it continues to give me an error

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
MyCSV = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Max von Klemperer\\Desktop\\places.xlsx")




list = []
counter = 0

for i in MyCSV["Column_Name"]:
    list[counter] = i
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: try this:

`ls = list(df[column_name].values)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Please submit as an official answer for people asking in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this:

```
ls = list(MyCSV[column_name].values)
```

add the `column_name`according to requirement

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = MyCSV['column_name'].to_list()
```

returns a list containing the element of the series corresponding to the column named 'column_name'. If MyCSV is already a pandas Series you can use

```
lst = MyCSV.to_list()
```